# Elliptic curves as $\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I apologize in advance if my question is rather trivial, but i have trouble understanding a basic fact about elliptic curves.. I have always wrote an elliptic curve $E$ as $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a lattice of rank 2, i.e. $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\tau$, $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$ the upper half plane.

Now I have read the equality $E=\mathbb{C}/\Lambda=\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{Z}$ where the last quotient is given by multiplication with $t^n$, $t=e^{i2\pi\tau}$.

My question is: how can $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ and $\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{Z}$ be the same thing? the two actions seem really different to me..

Comment: See about the Tate curve. I think you mean an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Z}((q))$, where $q = e^{2\pi i \tau}$

Comment: It's explained here about the p-adic uniformisation http://www.math.harvard.edu/~chaoli/doc/MumfordCurves.html

Comment: To start with, notice that $e^{2 \pi iz} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ has kernel $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your multiplicative model should be $\mathbf C^\times/t^{\mathbf Z}$, a quotient of two multiplicative groups, not $\mathbf C^\times/\mathbf Z$.